# Sulu: How to add an additional menu for a webspace?

Tags: sulu

Is there a way to create additional menus to a wabspace in Sulu CMS (1.6)? I only see the main manu in the options:

[image: Sulu Menu selection]

Thx a lot!
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more navigations using the XML definition of a webspace. The default webspace from the sulu-minimal repository is located at [`app/Resources/webspaces/example.com.xml`](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-minimal/blob/7f84b9f/app/Resources/webspaces/example.com.xml#L24) and already contains a `navigation` tag.

You can add more contexts like this:

```
<webspace>
    <!-- other tags -->
    <navigation>
        <contexts>
            <context key="main">
                <meta>
                    <title lang="en">Main Navigation</title>
                </meta>
            </context>
            <context key="footer">
                <meta>
                    <title lang="en">Footer Navigation</title>
                </meta>
            </context>
        </contexts>
    </navigation>
    <!-- other tags -->
</webspace>
```

Comment: Also this is an excellent Overview and introduction to the topic: https://blog.sulu.io/how-to-use-sulus-navigation-contexts